# the only fields filled by the user going to the query

Tags: php, sql

i want to filter data(s) from sql based from the users input . the thing is i have 3 fields, e.g (position,status,employer).but if the user did not input for a certain field(for example the field employer) that field will not included in the query (where clause).

heres my query

```
$result_set = mysqli_query($connection, "
SELECT fname, mname, lname, contactno ...
FROM tblapplicant, tblreq
WHERE tblapplicant.appid = tblreq.appid AND stat= '$a' AND emp= '$b' AND hired_pos= '$c'
");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `OR` instead of `AND`

```
SELECT fname,mname,lname,contactno ...
FROM tblapplicant 
inner join tblreq 
        on tblapplicant.appid=tblreq.appid 
where (stat= '$a' and  $a is not null)
   or (emp= '$b'  and $b is not null)
   or (hired_pos= '$c' and $c is not null)
```

Comment: Or's do rather change the meaning of the query

Answer (score 0):

You can append the additional criteria conditionally.

```
$sql = 'SELECT fname, mname, lname, contactno ...
FROM tblapplicant, tblreq
WHERE tblapplicant.appid = tblreq.appid ';

if ($a) { $sql .= "AND stat='$a' "; }
if ($b) { $sql .= "AND emp='$b' "; }
if ($c) { $sql .= "AND hired_pos='$c' "; }

$result_set = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

Comment: sorry im new to mysqli i got this err "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in...

Comment: That error could not come from the code we are working with here. Are you trying to `echo` the result set after executing the query?

Comment: yes it has  to be displayed (echo) @Don't Panic.

Comment: after ur given code above i put this ..
$count= mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0) {
echo " no record yet...";
} else {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo " something...";  @Don't Panic